# calling slideToggle jquery from codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using a jquery to slide a div "slidingDiv" when an anchor "show_hide" is clicked. I am wondering if i can show the div open when the page is loaded. Because i have textboxes in the div and want to have some text when the page is loaded sometimes.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function()
    {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

How can i do that using c#, asp.net..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call it in the code behind.

Simply expand the div when the DOM has loaded.  You already have the `document ready function`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".slidingDiv").show();
});
```

As a further explanation, when the page is loaded the function above will execute the code inside the `$(document).ready`.  jQuery will then select all classes with `slidingDiv` attached and show them.

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kcWyT/

Comment: Thank you! I am not clear. How can i expand without clicking anything by not using codebehind. Sorry, i am a newbie in jquery!

Comment: @Ram - I have added a simple explanation.  I will attach a JS fiddle and update.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to call a function from your code behind upon page load you could try:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"My function","MyFunction()",true);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "ScriptName", $(".slidingDiv").hide(); $(".show_hide").show(); $('.show_hide').click(function() { $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); });});", true);
```

the function is c# and registers a script that will be called at the init of the page.

Personally i prefer jQuery, but it works.

Greetings,